# Pyinstaller app closes and opens again after 30 seconds

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

this is the first time I’m using Pyinstaller. I’ve just used `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py` to create an app. Then I’ve adapted my main.spec and used `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.spec` The app works fine. However, upon clicking on it it loads for a very long time. Then it closes (without ever properly being open) and then finally opens after another 30s. The whole process takes longer than a minute. Does anybody have an idea what I could do?

My spec:

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/Frieda/Documents/GitHub/Advent Calender'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/proglog", prefix='proglog')
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tqdm", prefix='tqdm')
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imageio", prefix='imageio')
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imageio_ffmpeg", prefix='imageio_ffmpeg')
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http", prefix='http')
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi", prefix='certifi')
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chardet", prefix='chardet')
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/idna", prefix='idna')
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests", prefix='requests')
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3", prefix='urllib3')
a.datas += Tree("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/moviepy", prefix='moviepy')
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          Tree('./images', prefix='images'),
          Tree('./videos', prefix='videos'),
          Tree('./days', prefix='days'),
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='Adventskalender',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             name='Adventskalender.app',
             icon='/Users/Frieda/Documents/GitHub/Advent Calender/santa.icns',
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

Comment: well, you put everything into one large .exe file - how big is it? if it is several 100 MBs large, is it surprising that it takes a long time to load?

Comment: @pygri The .exe is about 170 MB. Is there a way I could make it any smaller?